# New window controller can't respond correctly

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, nswindowcontroller

I am a new programmer of `swift`. I tried to create a new window controller to deal with `DatePicker` stuff. Right now the new window only can be displayed and initialized but can not do further work.

- DatePicker Image

[image: image datePicker]

In the main ViewController, I included following lines

```
let datePickerVC = DatePicker()
datePickerVC.showWindow(nil)

import Cocoa

class DatePicker: NSWindowController{


@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: NSDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var datePickerView: NSView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateField: NSTextField!

var selectedDate = ""

convenience init(){
    self.init(windowNibName: "DatePicker")
    self.window?.level = .floating

}

@objc func chooseDateForUpload(){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
    selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.dateValue)
    dateField.stringValue = selectedDate
    print("selectedDate.dateValue: \(selectedDate)")
}

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    initWindowView()
}

func initWindowView(){
    datePicker.dateValue = Date()
    datePicker.target = self
    datePicker.action = #selector(chooseDateForUpload)
    let action = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.mouseExited
    self.datePicker.sendAction(on: action)
    chooseDateForUpload()
}
```

Currently, it hits to the `chooseDateForUpload` only once and can't do any further work. I expect it to react and get the date every time I change the `DatePicker` but nothing return so far after the initialization.

Comment: Your main viewcontroller is a subclass of NSWindownController?  I don't know how to say it nicely, but what you are showing doesn't make sense.

Comment: My main viewController is a sub class of NSViewController. I am not very familiar with swift so I might have some confusion between view controller and window controller. I am trying to display a new window including a datePicker in my program. is that make sense? How should I work with that?

Comment: And why do you have an instance each of NSDatePicker, NSView, and NSTextField inside the NSWindowController class?

Comment: I added a picture above. so Basically I want to add a page(window? or view) like that when I called it from the main view Controller

Comment: Use those instances with `NSViewController`, not with `NSWindowController`.